# weird ntdll.dll error with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, crash, bmp, ntdll

I have encountered a strange error with a BMP image. It doesn't seem to have something to do with a corrupted file as I've created a new image where the same error occurs again. I don't know if it's important, I'm using Iphoto Plus 4 (very old software) to produce the BMP.

Well, here's what happens. The image dimensions are 2350 x 1624 and if you set the pixel color in the coordinates x=1368, y=0 to 255,242,216 (I've found another combination where it happens, too: 254,242,216, maybe there are further combos...) the application crashes:

code to reproduce the error:

```
sprintf_s(avi,"e:\\1\\mmc.bmp");
IplImage *frame=cvLoadImage(avi,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);cvShowImage("video",frame);
cvWaitKey(1000);Sleep(6000);
```

the error message:

- Problemereignisname: APPCRASH
- Anwendungsname:  xyz.exe
- Anwendungsversion:   0.0.0.0
- Anwendungszeitstempel:   5217d7e2
- Fehlermodulname: ntdll.dll
- Fehlermodulversion:  6.0.6000.16386
- Fehlermodulzeitstempel:  4549bdc9
- Ausnahmecode:    c0000005
- Ausnahmeoffset:  00061884
- Betriebsystemversion:    6.0.6000.2.0.0.768.3
- Gebietsschema-ID:    1031
- ...

now, this ONLY happens with that particular pixel position and only a couple of sets of R,G,B values. Why? Anybody got an idea? ... I'm lost :-(

Comment: Upload somewhere this file and give us a link. BTW - try to use new OpenCV functions instead of old ones - http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: I'm using an older version for several reasons, I'd have to change too many things when upgrading and I mainly use it for frame handling in AVIs. Here's the pic.   http://www.file-upload.net/download-8001961/mmc.bmp.html
    (click on little green arrow download button)   Note that it is blank except for one pixel x,y = 1368,0 and RGB= 254,242,216. The image could contain of course any other information with just that pixel set to those values.